# Incomplete text from @PathVariable Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to send an ID to my controller using:

```html
<a href="/host/admin/sensor/downloadCSV/${sensor.id}" class="btn btn-primary"> Export CSV</a>
```

The content of `${sensor.id}` variable is: `testApp_provider.osom_component2.RT3`

In my controller I'm getting it with:

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadCSV/{sensorId}")
public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable final String sensorId) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("sensor:"+sensorId);
    return null;
}
```

But the output of the `println` is:

`sensor:testApp_provider.osom_component2`

I'm losing the last part: `.RT3`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to,

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadCSV/{sensorId:.+}")
public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable final String sensorId) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("sensor:"+sensorId);
    return null;
}
```

As everything behind the last dot is a file extension for Spring, so it truncates it by default.

The other, global solution would be to set `useRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch` property to `false` when registering the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

More cleaner way however is to add trailing `/` slash at the end

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadCSV/{sensorId}/")
```